# Retrieve the no. of followers of those persons who retweeted a tweet using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Input: Any 2 tweets of a particular twitter handle.

Output: Find out who retweeted them. Then display 10 retweeters in the descending order of their no. of followers.

I have to build a UI for the same in Rails.

Any help, how should I start off with?

Comment: There isn't anything specific to Rails here.  Are you stuck with the basic logic, or you stuck how to particularly do this in Ruby? As in what gems to use, how to use them etc. ?

Comment: @Swanand I want to build this [Multunus](http://puzzle.multunus.com/) kind of a web application for any one twitter handle(going for Firefox). Yeah, seems like you are right.

Comment: Are you trying to get a tweet which has a number of re tweets and the user who re tweeted them in order of there followers. Correct me If I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what are you asking in the context of Rails, but this might help you get started.

Twitter API Documentation for [retweeted_by](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/%3aid/retweeted_by)

It accepts the ID of a tweet and returns a collection of retweeters. You can set the limit of retweeters as well by passing in some optional parameters.  More details in the documentation.